# Correct way to instantiate an array in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to declare and instantiate an array named 'canines' that had 25 elements and will hold 'dog' objects...
Is this the best way to do this or is there another formate that would be more correct?

canines[25] = Dog﻿﻿

Comment: use this Dog[] canines = new Dog[25];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dog[] canines = new Dog[25];
```

Have a look at some of the many online java resources

Comment: check my comment.

Comment: Check my answer.